# Sahi Script, using variable in _assertEqual

Tags: sahi

I want to put variable to check if is Equal some text in the page, but in this way - doens't work:

```
function check($value) {

_assertEqual($value, " - VERSION", _getText(_heading1($value, " - VERSION")));
_click(_link("Edit[1]"));
}
check ("HELP")
```

The result:

> _assertEqual("HELP", " - VERSION", _getText(_heading1("HELP", " - VERSION"))); Error: The parameter passed to _getText was not found on
>   the browser at check (scripts/check.sah:3) at 2015-1-28 11:53:29

---

So, if I do in this way, it's works:

```
function check($value) {
_assertEqual("HELP - VERSION", _getText(_heading1("HELP - VERSION")));
_click(_link("Edit[1]"));
}
check ("HELP")
```

How to put this variable to works correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of _getText,  try   _set

for example:

```
  var $helpVersion;
  _set($helpVersion, _heading1("HELP - VERSION").textContent);
  _assertEqual("HELP - VERSION", $helpVersion);
```

Comment: Yes, it's works this, but I want to put the parameter in ("HELP - VERSION")

Comment: This, should work.        _assertEqual("HELP - VERSION", _getText(_heading1($value+" - VERSION")));

Answer (score 0):

Rumen, the following is incorrect.

```
_heading1($value, " - VERSION")
```

A single string parameter has to be passed to _heading1. In your case, joining $value and " - VERSION" will work.

```
_heading1($value + " - VERSION")
```

The above change is what you need. So, your final function will look like this:

```
function check($value) {
_assertEqual("HELP - VERSION", _getText(_heading1($value + " - VERSION")));
_click(_link("Edit[1]"));
}
check ("HELP")
```